# Can anyone explain how to simplify this set arithmetic issue?

Tags: computer-science, set-theory, computer-science-theory

Can anyone help with explaining how to simplify this? 
X and Y are two sets. 
Simplify the following:

> (Y − X)∩X

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about set theory and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is empty set since you are taking only other part from X with (Y-X), then intersecting with X.

E.g. **Y = [1,2,3,4], X=[3,4,5]. Y-X=[1,2] => (Y − X)∩X = [] = ∅**